# Exceeding 100% vertical height with bordered table

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

On full screen view this code produces a vertical scroll bar. Why does this occur when the table's height is set to `100%`? I've tried changing the `box-sizing` property to `border-box` to include the `1px` border width inside the table's `100%` height. Is changing the table height to something like `99.999%` really the best solution or using `overflow:hidden`? Is there a better solution to get rid of this vertical scroll bar? It seems to be the height of just `1px` pushing everything over 100%.

**I want to get rid of that vertical scroll bar**

```css
@import url('https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/latest/normalize.css');
html, body{height:100%}
table{border-collapse:collapse; width:100%; height:100%}
td, th{border:1px solid #222; padding:10px}
td div{
  display:inline-block; background-color:#222; color:#eee; padding:5px;
  margin:0 2.5%
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr><th rowspan="4">UI</th> <td><div>box-sizing</div></td></tr> 
      <tr><td><div>resize</div></td></tr>
      <tr><div><td><div>cursor</div></td></div></tr>
      <tr><td><div>content</div></td></tr>   
      <tr>
        <th rowspan="6">BASIC BOX</th>
        <td><div>display</div> <div>visibility</div></td>
      </tr> 
      <tr><td><div>overflow</div></td></tr>
      <tr><td><div>clip</div></td></tr>
      <tr><td><div>width</div> <div>height</div></td></tr>
      <tr><td><div>margin</div> <div>padding</div></td></tr>
      <tr><td><div>float</div> <div>clear</div></td></tr>  
      <tr>
        <th rowspan="6">BEAUTIFICATION</th>
        <td><div>...</div> <div>...</div></td>
      </tr> 
      <tr><td><div>...</div></td></tr>
      <tr><td><div>...</div></td></tr>
      <tr><td><div>...</div> <div>...</div></td></tr>
      <tr><td><div>...</div> <div>...</div></td></tr>
      <tr><td><div>...</div> <div>...</div></td></tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hmm - I put it into a codepen (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bgrpEP), and there is NO scrollbar. Maybe a browser thing that `normalize.css` doesn't "neutralize"?

Comment: @Johannes You don't have a vertical scrollbar like this? http://imgur.com/a/VhXsW. It seems to be over by just 1px on fullscreen causing a scrollbar

Comment: no, I don't. Look at my link - I changed the window layout to have the code panels to the right and have the result in a portrait-mode panel - no scrollbar.

Comment: @Johannes Interesting. I'm using google chrome on windows 8.1 pro at 1920 x 1080px resolution. This doesn't seem to be a browser inconsistency or something like it though. I can test other machines to make sure. Here's another screenshot with panels on right: http://imgur.com/a/caWKL

Comment: I am on a Mac and I tried it on four browsers now: Firefox and Safari: No scrollbar. Chrome and Opera: Scrollbar. It was gone for a moment in Chrome when I added `margin:0` to `table`, but it came back...

Comment: @Johannes Had no idea such simple code would cause browser inconsistencies. I checked and you are right about there not being a scrollbar in Firefox. Unfortunately *hacking* the code might be the best fix to this but still part of why I asked this question is to understand how and why this happens.

Comment: Taking off the border or using the `outline` property gets rid of the scrollbar. I'm stumped as to why this code produces such a result.

Comment: I found something - look at my new answer, please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like I found a solution:

I suspected that the problem was caused by `border-collapse`- when you remove it, there is no scrollbar (also not in Chrome)

So I actually *added* the same `border: 1px solid #222;` to `table` which you had assigned to `td, th`. They collapse anyway, but the scrollbar disappeared that way.

Here's the codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dNzONe

(change view to have the code panels to the right instead of on top)

Note: I don't actually see a border at the very top, but I didn't see one in your version either...

Comment: What made you think to **add** the border? That seems so counter-intuitive and thank you for solving this for me in way that wasn't a seemingly unnecessary hack.

Comment: Hmm, it *was* kind of intuition... ;-) I thought it would have to do with border-collapse: At all inner cell borders there are two borders which are merged into one. Only at the outer side there is just one border each, so make that also two by adding border to the table. That way there are two borders merged into one *everywhere*, which maybe the browser would be able to handle better.  I know that sounds very strange, but you asked...